# Adding a "clickable item" in PreferenceDialog in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin

I have lost some hours trying to figure out how to use this correctly...

I already have a functional PreferenceDialog in my project. I'm using some CheckBoxPreference's and ListPreference's and managing the functionalities using OnSharedPreferenceChange.

Now I have added a simple  item in my PreferenceScreen (to work as an "About" button), but I can't add a ClickListener to this item.

In my prefs.xml:

```
<Preference
android:title="Sobre"
android:summary="Sobre o aplicativo"
android:key="botaoSobre" />
```

I've searched and found many tips to add using Java, but I can't find one for Xamarin Android. For Java, I can use OnPreferenceClickListener like this:

```
Preference myPref = findPreference( "MY_PREF" );
    myPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener( new OnPreferenceClickListener()
    {
        public boolean onPreferenceClick( Preference pref )
        {
              // Run your custom method
        }
    } );
```

But I don't know how to use it in Xamarin. I've tried any possibly way I know, but just doesn't work.

Someone knows how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. Actually I've figured out how to fix.

I've re-looked how a button works and got the right way to add a functionality to  item. Just use this:

```
Preference button = (Preference)FindPreference("YOUR_BUTTON");
            button.PreferenceClick += delegate {
                        // YOUR CODE GOES HERE
            };
```